# VBA how to pass a string array to range

Tags: vba, excel

The usual issue is to pass range to array, but this time I need to do the opposite. I want to pass various size string array to a range.
BR Michał

Comment: What is the problem? To determine the size of the range? Well you have the bounds (LBound and UBound)) of the array.

Comment: Do I have to set a range?
Can I assing array to range after setting?
Like rng = array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value of a range from an array, we must first determine the size of that range dependent of the arrays size. For this we can use the bounds (`LBound` and `UBound`) of the array.

Then, if the array fits into the range, we can simply do `range.value = arr`.

Example:

```
Sub test()

 Cells.ClearContents

 ' one dimensional array; base 0
 aSArr = Array("This", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings")

 Set r1 = Range("C3").Resize(1, 1 + UBound(aSArr))
 r1.Value = aSArr

 Set r2 = Range("C5").Resize(1 + UBound(aSArr), 1)
 r2.Value = Application.Transpose(aSArr)

 ' two dimensional array; base 1
 aSArr = [{"This", "is", "an"; "array", "of", "strings"}]

 Set r3 = Range("E6").Resize(UBound(aSArr, 1), UBound(aSArr, 2))
 r3.Value = aSArr


End Sub
```